# When retrieving the storage summary of repos in Artifactory, is there a way to order them by size?

Tags: bash, artifactory

I'm trying to view what repos are taking up the most storage space in artifactory by using the below API call, but I can't find a way to order them. I also seen in Jfrogs documentation that you cant sort based on properties. Any suggestions as to how do to do this?

https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-GetStorageSummaryInfo

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 4):

In this case, `jq` is your friend!

Pipe the output of the API to a `jq` with using the `sort_by()` functions.

Example:

```
curl -s -uadmin:password https://server/artifactory/api/storageinfo | jq '[.repositoriesSummaryList[] | {repoKey: .repoKey, itemsCount: .itemsCount, usedSpaceInBytes: .usedSpaceInBytes}] | sort_by(.usedSpaceInBytes)'
```

You can play around with the options.

Look for more details on the `jq` sorting in [this good jq sorting doc](https://queirozf.com/entries/jq-sorting-json-objects).